# How to Wait on Async function inside array.forEach in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to make an `async` request within `foreach` to fetch data in order user it later but its not working for me.

I know `Array.Foreach` is a synchronous function so I even tried $.when.done but still it does not wait until it finish.

I could have used callback if it was a single value but its an array .
Is there a better way to handle this by callback to achieve waiting on `async` request before moving next?

```
browseItems.forEach((browseItem: any) => {

   AsynchFunction();

   cosole.log("Step 2")  
}
function AsynchFunction(){
   console.log("Step 1")
}
```

I am trying to get an output like

Step 1

Step 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you start using async functions, you go either of two ways: `callbacks` or `promises`. In the case of the above code, you just need to define a callback function to be called after the async function returns. See sample below:

```
browseItems.forEach((browseItem: any) => {
   AsynchFunction(postProcess);   
}
function AsynchFunction(callback){
   console.log("Step 1");
   if(asyncProcessDone){
       callback();
   }
}
function postProcess(){
    console.log("Step 2")
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Building on [@basarat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32389768/1396477), I found that this works quite well if you are using the `async/await` feature in TypeScript (as of TS 1.7 requiring ES6 target):

```
async function processData(data: any[]) {
  const promises = data.map(async (item) => {
    await doSomeAsyncStuff(item);
    //you can do other stuff with the `item` here
  });
  await Promise.all(promises);

  //you can continue with other code here that will execute after all the async code completes
}

async function doSomeAsyncStuff(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //call some async library or do a setTimeout and resolve/reject the promise
  });
}
```

**Update:** `async` and `await` are now [available for TypeScript code targeting ES5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9175) as well in the `master` branch of TypeScript, soon to be released as TypeScript 2.1.  You can install it today using `npm install --save-dev typescript@next`

**Update:** This feature is available for all ES targets in the current version of TypeScript.  The one caveat I have noticed is that if you are targeting ES5 or ES3, you will need to provide a Promise polyfill or the code will fail on older browsers.

Comment: this looks neat, but doesn't seem to actually work. First, you'd need to return something from the `map`... but even then it doesn't appear to wait afterward.

Comment: @dcsan, in TypeScript, when you `await` a function that returns a promise, the containing `async` function automatically returns a `Promise`, even if the promise is `Promise<void>`.  You don't need to return anything out of the `.map` function.  I have used this pattern many times and it works well.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a better way to handle this by callback to achieve waiting on async req before moving next

If you are using promises you can use a function like `Promise.all`:

```
var promises = browseItems.map((browseItem: any) => AsynchFunction());
Promise.all(promises).then((values)=>{});
```